PasswordSafe does not work correctly after 24.04 upgrade
PasswordSafe is nice application to store passwords. It is not possible modify entries now.


Upgrade from what?

Upgrade from 22.02... LTS

Are you sure? There has never been a Ubuntu 22.02 Regardless have you verified that the app works on Ubuntu 24.04? The maker may need to update their app.

I am not sure, Ubuntu was version 22.?? . I did not verify application  before upgrade.

Ubuntu was 22.04.13. I found it in /var/log/dist-upgrade/20240910-0755/main.log

There has never been any such version as 22.04.13 are you even sure it is Ubuntu?

Here is part from main.log. I am sure it was Ubuntu version 22.04.13: 2022-08-24 15:37:14,924 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg.focal', '/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.d/ubuntu-advantage-upgrades.cfg']'
2022-08-24 15:37:14,924 INFO uname information: 'Linux saphire 5.4.0-124-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 02:23:37 UTC 2022 x86_64'
2022-08-24 15:37:15,316 INFO apt version: '2.0.9'
2022-08-24 15:37:15,316 INFO python version: '3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18)
[GCC 9.4.0]'
2022-08-24 15:37:15,319 INFO release-upgrader version '22.04.13' started

This is not any version of Ubuntu.  release-upgrader version '22.04.13 Is not the version of the OS.

OK David DE. May be the old version was 22.bla.blabla. PasswordSafe worked in old version very good. After update to version Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS PasswordSafe does not work. There is not problem PasswordSafe worked in old version 22.??.??. Problem is PasswordSafe does not work in new version Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS after upgrade.

The old version was Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, I found some remark today.

I changed language from English to Russian using "Manage" "Select language". We all need to learn Russian!
